# iOS dynamoDB getItem result for lists/sets not showing up properly

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

First of all, I've searched mercilessly through the Amazon DynamoDB documentation and searched through every forum I could think of.

What I want to do is very simple. I simply want to do a `getItem` command on a DynamoDB table and parse the item attribute that is a list or a string set.

```
AWSDynamoDBGetItemInput *getItem = [AWSDynamoDBGetItemInput new];
getItem.tableName = @"tester";

AWSDynamoDBAttributeValue *hashValue = [AWSDynamoDBAttributeValue new];
hashValue.S = @"Washington";
getItem.key = @{@"aaa": hashValue};

[[dynamoClient getItem:getItem] continueWithBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {
    if (!task.error) {
        AWSDynamoDBGetItemOutput *response = task.result;
        NSDictionary *customer = response.item;
        NSLog(@"%@",customer);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"%@",task.error);
    }
    return nil;
}];
```

- Table name: "tester"
- hashKey: "aaa"
- attribute1: List called "Sub Tabs"
- attribute2: String set called "stringSet"

Here is the output that I am getting

```
2015-01-17 00:19:51.535 DiscoveryPage[7157:302848] {
"Sub Tags" = "<AWSDynamoDBAttributeValue: 0x7fafd1790000> {\n}";
aaa = "<AWSDynamoDBAttributeValue: 0x7fafd178f9a0> {\n    S = Washington;\n}";
stringSet = "<AWSDynamoDBAttributeValue: 0x7fafd178fed0> {\n    
SS =     (\n        10,\n        11,\n        12,\n        13\n    );\n}";}
```

The output for "Sub Tags" is a "List" attribute... how the heck do I parse this?

For the string set I could probably do some whacky string manipulation to get the 4 elements out of this string set (10,11,12,13) but that seems ridiculous that I have to do that. Does DynamoDB really not give me output for my list and give me my string set as ONE giant string?

Am I missing something? Is there a tool that parses DynamoDB getItemOutput that I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you are using the latest version of the AWS Mobile SDK for iOS. If you use 2.0.15 or later, you do not need to parse `customer` since it is [already parsed](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/Classes/AWSDynamoDBGetItemOutput.html#//api/name/item). It is an `NSDictionary` of `NSString` / `AWSDynamoDBAttributeValue` pair. You are printing out the entire dictionary, so it seems like it is a string, but actually it is not.  You can take a look at the [integration test](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/blob/master/AWSiOSSDKTests/AWSDynamoDBTests.m#L378) for how to access data in a dictionary in Objective-C.

Comment: I'm getting same issue. So how can I read this? The link you posted for [integration test](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/blob/master/AWSiOSSDKTests/AWSDynamoDBTests.m#L378)  is not any more.